# Starting service only if its not already up - docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that controls a few services. 
One of which are a db service. I don't always want to restart the db service.

Example docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  base:
    commad: "echo somecommand"
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=usr
      - POSTGRES_USER=use
      - POSTGRES_DB=usr
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

How can I do `docker-compose up`, but if the db service (postgres in my case) is already up, making sure it wont restart.

Im currently using docker-compose down/up, and my db restarts.

I tried to add `--scale postgres=0` to my docker-compose up command, but then it shuts down postgres all together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `docker-compose up  --no-recreate`.

Ref https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: but I do want to recreate base service. Is there a way to specify which container I dont want to recreate? or specify for docker-compose down, specific services to kill/remove?

Comment: `docker-compose up service_name`? this way you control which service to run.

Comment: But `docker-compose down service_name` is not bringing down the service

Comment: @NotSoShabby no you need ‘docker-compose rm -s service’ instead